# How do I log e-mails sent to a google group?

Tags: email, g-suite, groups

I'm setting up a non-profit organization with e-mails @companyname.com, and I've begun using Google Apps for this.

Can I use Google Apps e-mail to maintain a history of all the e-mails sent to a Group? How do I set this up (it is non-obvious for all my searching)?

Comment: Does the archive need to be searchable by users, or is it for your own use only?

Comment: It needs to be searchable by users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just yesterday, Google started providing Google Groups for Google Apps.  You can create groups that are much more like discussion forums and will provide a history of all messages sent to the group.

The feature is only available to premium and education/non-profit accounts.  As a non-profit, you can convert a standard Google Apps account to educational for access to this feature.

http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72223

Answer (score 1):

Our company uses Google Apps for email and what not, and we have a Qmail server set as the outbound gateway and it forks all email to the attended address and also to a mail archive server that sets there and listens on port 25 and dumps all the messages. We also have the an inbound setting in Google set to send a duplicate message of that to our mail archiver. You could also have a Qmail box as the inbound gateway to do do the same forking depending on how your setup is. That will get all email archived so might be a little overkill for what your looking for but if nothing else it might spawn some other ideas.